# Change text area background to white on focus css3

Tags: css

I have the following **css** code....(only relevant portion)

```
.register {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #000000;
    }
    .register h3 {
    margin: 0 15px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #909090;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    .register div {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    border: none;
    }
    .register label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px;
    }
    .register input[type=text], .register input[type=password] {
    width: 65%;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Tahoma,Sans-Serif;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    }
    .register input[type=text]:focus, .register input[type=password]:focus {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .register textarea{
    width: 65%;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Tahoma,Sans-Serif;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    }
    div.textarea > * {
    vertical-align:middle
    }
```

I require the **text-area field to change to white background on focus**(focus background), as in other input fields in the form.

I have provided a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shels123/t5SNE/17/) of my current form.

Help requested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are only using `:focus` on input

```
.register input[type=text]:focus, .register input[type=password]:focus {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Change to this:

```
.register input[type=text]:focus, .register input[type=password]:focus, .register textarea:focus {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t5SNE/19/)**

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering you have already done it for other fields then why can't for textarea. Anyway update your CSS like below.

```
.register input[type=text]:focus, .register input[type=password]:focus, .register textarea:focus {
background: #FFFFFF;
}
```